# How do I screen scrape google Maps places?

Tags: maps, screen, scrape

I have this map, https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=211195694269703855460.0004a7072cf25d4660761&ie=UTF8&ll=41.40205,2.157927&spn=0.103847,0.133132&source=embed

I would like to download all the locations and copy them into a db

where can i find the JSON?

does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click the share icon and download the map as a KML file. Then you'll get all the locations in an XML file you can parse and add to a database.

[image]

Comment: Trick doesn't work now on above URL. Anything changed ?

Comment: Google have made XML export 'easier'. I've updated my answer with the current method.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an easy way to screen scrape.  However, there is an easy way to get access to the same information: the Google Places API.  See
   https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/